# PHP: iterate through array and assign a customer to a user, in turn

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

**Purpose**

Every time an operator manually adds a Customer to the program, he/she assigns an area to the customer as well.

There are many users and every one has one or more areas assigned.

Once the operator enters a customer and assigns an area to it, a user should be assigned to that customer, but not always the same user, it has to be a different one every time (based on a area_customer table) and this has to be in turn (1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2...).

So if 3 users are assigned to an area, the created customer is first assigned to the first user, later on a new customer is entered and is assigned to the second user, a third customer is entered and is assigned to the third user. At this point all starts again. If a fourth customer is created, the first user is assigned to this, an so forth.

**Details**

I have 4 MySQL tables:

- Users
- Areas
- Area_Users
- Customers

`Users` table has a unique id `user_id` and other fields for each user.

`Areas` table has a unique id `area_id` and a name field.

`Area_Users` table has the `area_id` and `user_id` only, this is where the assignment of areas has been made, so every user has assigned to himself one or more areas.

`Customer` table has a unique id `customer_id`, has an `area_id` (that relates to the `Areas` table) and has a `user_assigned_id` (related to Users table)

**What I need to accomplish:**

Every time a customer is added to the program, the responsible manually inserts all of the data on that customer, INCLUDING THE AREA the customer is assigned to.

At this point a row is inserted in the MySQL table `Customer`, but the `user_assigned_id` should be added programmatically (and not manually by the person).

The choice of which `user_id` to place in the `user_assigned_id` needs to be calculated from the `Areas` table. It should be a different person every time in turn.

This is the `Areas` table:

```
|  area_id  |    name   |
-------------------------    
|     1     |    Z1     |
|     2     |    Z2     |
```

So let's say this is the `Area_Users` table:

```
|  area_id  |  user_id  |
-------------------------    
|     1     |     4     |
|     1     |     6     |
|     2     |     1     |
|     2     |     2     |
|     2     |     3     |
|     2     |     5     |
|     2     |     6     |
```

So, the area #1 is assigned to user 4 and 6, while area #2 is assigned to 1,2,3,5 and 6. (Note: User 6 has 2 area assigned)

At this point the person creates a record for area #2, this has to be assigned to user 1, the next record that will be created goes to user #2, than #3 then #5 and then #6. Than again from #1.

Same for area #1, the first goes to user #4, then #6 then #4, then #6, and so forth...

My idea is to first find the Area data:

```
//Codeigniter 
$areas_data = $this->db->get_where('areas', ['area_id' => 1]);
```

Then find how many users are in those area:

```
$tot_users_area = $areas_data->num_rows();
```

Then I can iterate through them, but how do I know what was the last assignment? And, in the case of Area #1, after user #4 comes #6 (or could be #124) so how do I go onto the next one?

Comment: "At this point the person creates a record for area #2, this has to be assigned to user 1..."."  Does this 'assignment' mean 'a record for this triplet (customer_id, area_id, user_assigned_id) is created in the Customers table?  Is the customer_id in the Customers table auto-incremented?  If not, where does that value come from?  if it is equal to the user_id, why is that field necessary (or why is user_assigned_id field necessary)?

Comment: "Areas table has a unique id area_id"..Actually your area table doesn't have uniqe id..There is  a many-to-many relationship between users and area..This is why u are struggle..And this database design may cause problems for your application when your application needs new features in the past..I'm  also conserned about if you need a Customer table..What's the difference between a customer and a user?

Comment: Also don't forget the three principles..KISS, YAGNI & DRY..

Comment: So sorry, I totally forgot to write about one table... see my edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are actually looking for is `ROUND ROBIN METHOD`. You have to circle the users while assigning a customer.

**WHAT YOU CAN DO**

Whenever you are assinging the customer, you have to make another insert in a temporary table .

This temporary table tracks which was the last user `(userid)` that was assigned and the area of that customer, and when you will be assinging the customer once again you will first consult this temporary table to check which user was last assigned and just increment that userid and assign the customer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, and the customer_id field in the Customers table is auto-incremented, you'd need to check the Customers table for the "last assignment", as you put it.

After you get all the $areas_data:

```
$areas_data = $this->db->get_where('areas', ['area_id' => 1]);
```

Loop through each (user_id, area) pair in the Customers table and see what exists.  When you find a pair that does not exist, add it:

```
foreach($areasdata as $key => $areaDatum) {
    $result = $this->db->get_where('customers', array('area_id' => $areaDatum['area_id'], 'user_assigned_id' => $areaDatum['user_id']));
    if(!result) {
        $data = array('area_id' => $areaDatum['area_id'], 'user_assigned_id' = > $areaDatum['user_id']);
        $this->db->insert('customers', $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: I saw your answer, probably you didn't get what I needed to accomplish. Or perhaps I was not able to communicate it correctly: Every time a customer is added to the DB and assigned to an area, a user has to get that customer assigned. The area assigned to the Customer is done by hand, not in an automatic way. The user assigned to the customer has to be automatic.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a simple demonstration with arrays without using codeigniter and database..

```
<?php
$customers=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
$users=[1,2,3,4];
$usercustomers = [];
$userslen=count($users);


foreach($customers as $customer)
{
    if($customer > $userslen){

        $usercustomers = array('user'     => $customer%$userslen,
                               'customer' => $customer);
        var_dump($usercustomers);
        echo "<br>";

    }
    foreach($users as $user)
    {

        if($customer%$user==0 && $customer==$user){

            $usercustomers = array('user'     => $user,
                                   'customer' => $customer);

            var_dump($usercustomers);
            echo "<br>";
         }

    }

}



?>
```

At this point you may consider using an ORM package(Which provides reusuble solutions for situations like that)..Because there is a many to one relationship between users and customers..Using an ORM there is an easy solution.. http://www.krueckeberg.org/notes/relationships.html.. Also search the keywords `"on cascade delete"`and `"on cascade insert"`..It will be more easy using an ORM and cascading.."There is no need to reinvent the wheel"..

There is a many to many relationship between areas and users..Changing your database design may help you,and strongly recomended..In your current design what if you need to get all areas?There is not a primary key in the table areas..Also what if you need to get track assignments using date?In this solution you can add a date field into AssignedInto table and keep track assignemts etc.AssignedInto table provides the relation between the Users and Areas..

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)

http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561

[image]

An ORM package called doctrine..

http://www.doctrine-project.org/